# Magento relative URLs having frontend parameter appended

Tags: url, magento, frontend

This is driving me nuts. When Google first started indexing my site, I was ending up with a load of duplicate pages, the only difference between them being a "frontend" parameter in the URL. I've told Google to ignore that, but I can't work out where it's coming from.

Basically, any relative URLs are getting ?frontend=xxxxx appended to them, where xxxxx is a long hex string.

Something is also adding a hidden input field on any forms on the page (the newsletter form and the search form), called "frontend", containing the same hex v
alue. So presumably some javascript is doing this, given that the code for those forms makes no mention of this parameter.

I don't see it all the time. I do tend to see it whenever a bot accesses my site - e.g. if I run the W3C validator and output the source. I've occasionally seen it when I visit the site myself, but most of the time it's not there.

I'm using the Fooman Speedster plugin, and I'm guessing it's somehow related to that or caching, that maybe the hex string is a version signature or something, and the reason I don't see it myself most of the time is that the page is already cached.

But I've grepped the code folders and I can't find the damn thing.

Google's no help, since "magento frontend" is a pretty common term. Would really appreciate any pointers from anyone who's encountered this before.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/magento-session-fixation-workaround

I would disable "Use SID on Frontend" if you are running multiple stores.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have that switched off, and I'm only running one store.

Comment: Actually, I looked at that again, which led me to some other stuff, and it definitely is the session ID I'm seeing. Looks like it's always getting added in for relative URLs, regardless of the setting chosen. I could work around that by using prefixing all relative URLs with getBaseURl. The bigger problem is that hidden input field that's getting added in each form is causing HTML validation to fail.